# SVN: Copied version different from original? :(

Tags: svn

Riddle me this...

```
$ svn cp $SVNROOT/fdps/tasks/6307b $SVNROOT/fdps/tasks/6145
((standard copy/commit output from svn))
$ svn cat $SVNROOT/fdps/tasks/6307b/include/rfdps_global.h | grep -i "^#define trunc"
$ svn cat $SVNROOT/fdps/tasks/6145/include/rfdps_global.h | grep -i "^#define trunc"
#define trunc(a) (a >= 0 ? floor(a) : ceil(a))
```

Huh...?
Why is the copied version different from the non-copied version?

Comment: What is `$SVNROOT`, i.e. are you working here with repository or with working copy?

Comment: Repository.  svn+ssh://karen@xenon/development/svn

Comment: Also, how come `svn cp` does not produce any output?

Comment: Also, if `svn cp` works directly with repository how come you didn't have to provide commit message (-m)?

Comment: I had to dig that line out of my bash history, the output has since scrolled off the screen.  I did have to provide a commit message.  I'll edit the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh.... investigating that better led me to the answer: the directory 6145 *already existed*, having been made from an earlier copy of trunk and thus not including the changes on the 6307b task.  Hence, it just copied 6307b to a subdirectory of 6145  :Þ

Well, the fix is easy enough  :)